# Repeat table rows when finished

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

it a Twitter script which tweets from a tweets library divided into categories. When the user finish all tweets in a category, repeat this operation from the beginning.

I want to repeat the MySQL table rows when all finished.

I select one row every time which I didn't select before and record it in another table that I selected this row. But I want when all rows are finished to repeat the same operation.

This is my code until now:

```
$sel_tweet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tweets_library` WHERE `cat_id` IN ($row_users[my_cats]) AND `id` NOT IN (SELECT `tweet_id` FROM `auto_tweet_check` WHERE `user_id`='$row_users[id]') ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,1");
if (@mysql_num_rows($sel_tweet) > 0) {
    $row_tweet = @mysql_fetch_array($sel_tweet);
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, $YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $row_users['access_token_oauth_token'], $row_users['access_token_oauth_token_secret']);
    $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $row_tweet['msg']));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `auto_tweet_check`(`id`,`user_id`,`tweet_id`,`tweet_cat_id`)VALUES(NULL,'$row_users[id]','$row_tweet[id]','$row_tweet[cat_id]')");
}
else {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `auto_tweet_check` WHERE `user_id`='$row_users[id]' AND `tweet_cat_id`='?????????'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [mysql_data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php). Please note that the `mysql` functions are deprecated.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Do something here
}
mysql_data_seek($result, 0); // 0 is the first record
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Do something else here
}
```